# Creating slanted variable name in starplot legend

Tags: r, plot

How can I make my variable name in the legend (at the bottom of my starplot) slanted to avoid overcrowding each other in starplot. Please see attached picture of my star plot:

[image]

```
a = stars(norm_data[, 2:14], full = TRUE,radius = TRUE,len = 0.6, 
         key.loc = c(8,2.5),
         labels = norm_data$`Garden type`, 
         main = "Provision of Ecosystem services covid", draw.segments = TRUE,
         lwd = 0.25, lty = par("lty"), xpd = TRUE,
         srt = 90)
```